# Chosen not working on elements from AJAX call

Tags: ajax, jquery-chosen

I have a form which populates div elements based on selections from a select box using an AJAX call.

The content of the populated div is a multiselect box that I want Chosen to apply to. Unfortunately it seems that the 'chzn-select' is not firing, no doubt due to this being pulled in dynamically.

I have added this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    </script>
```

To the bottom of the code that is pulled in by AJAX, but it is still not firing. Any ideas on how to make this work as desired?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved myself. Will post for future reference. I put the Chosen calls in their own function on my original page that calls the AJAX:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function doChosen() {
        $(".chzn-select").chosen();
        $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});
    }
    </script>
```

And in the AJAX script itself, I added a call to the function after the responseText part:

```
    document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=oXmlHttp.responseText
    doChosen();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using chosen(), try change() method. It works on change event.
try:

```
$(".chzn-select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                // do your coding here
              });

        })
        .trigger('change');
```

Comment: I'm just looking for a method to fire .chosen() after the ajax call is made, not when I change the contents of the select box.

Comment: Try   $("#selbox-id").chosen();