# Make ajax request and success data show in id <select></select> part

Tags: javascript, php, html

[See this link](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/jquery-chosen.php)..
My HTML page contains a similar multiple select drop down. Something like this -

```
<select id="box" data-placeholder="Choose from available option.." class="chosen-select student-select" name="classes" multiple style="width:310px;" tabindex="4">
</select>
```

In this select drop down, I'm trying to print `<option></option>` by making an Ajax request and showing the success data there.

When I used a simple `<select></select>` without using the `chosen` style, I can see the options there. But when I use the `chosen` style near the `select`  (multiple selection) then is doesn't shows the options.

```
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = data;
```

I am doing something like this.Please, help why it doesn't show me when I used that chosen effect.?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#customer').change(function(){
var Id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '../folder/page1.php',
data: "mid="+Id,
success: function( data ) {
alert(data);
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = data;
}
});
});
});
```

Comment: Share your ajax code..

Comment: but ajax code is working as charm..

Comment: what data are you getting after ajax success request ?

Comment: html data that is <option value""><option>

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initiate chosen after the new html has been loaded in the page via ajax.
This has been answered in this question.

[Chosen not working on elements from AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746889/chosen-not-working-on-elements-from-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

You only can show the HTML output in DOM. I am assuming that you're getting options after ajax request. Just try to change like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#customer').change(function(){
var Id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '../folder/page1.php',
data: "mid="+Id,
 success: function( data ) {
    $("#box").html(data);
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
 }
 });
});
});
```

After AJAX call you should initialize your select box. try and share the results.

Comment: It's okay. In your case when dom gets refresh, your plugin initiates the select box with its options, if you have that time. But now in current situation, you're adding options after dom being loaded. So you only need to re initialize your select box after success ajax request.

Comment: can I share my php page to you just check once? If you are free then please share your mailID

Comment: Please Check mail. I had ping there.

Comment: vineet verma
vkv000@gmail.com is this yours.?